# Export data from Excel to SQL Server (right from Excel, not using SQL Server data wizard)

Tags: sql-server, excel, export

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several rows I would like to store that data in a SQL Server table right from Excel. I mean, I would like to press a bottom in Excel (not in SQL Server) to store this table in my SQL Server database.

I have been googling but every solution I find is using SQL Server Export/Import wizard. Is there any way to do this right from Excel?

Thank you! I appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried SSIS?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I made a lot of reports that download data from Sql Server to Excel by clicking button in Excel, storing data is possible too. You must create ODBC connection in your Windows and by name of this ODBC connection you must connect from Excel VBA to Sql Server, then you can query your database with sql: select, update, insert, SP, etc. Maybe latter I will be able to paste some example

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is but it will require some development on your side. For example you can create VBA macro like the one shown in this article

[Export Import Excel SQL](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm)

You could create SSIS package, but this requires running it outside of the Excel or otherwise another macro will be needed to call the SSIS jobs,

You could use PowerShell and OpenXML if the Excel documents are xlsx only.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look too